# Get HandlerMethod from url String

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to know which Controller would process specific url. Unfortunately I dont have available HttpServletRequest, just url as String.

For example given url is: `https://localhost:8090/name-of-product/147/product`

ProductController has mapping: `@GetMapping("/{name}/{code}/product")`

And I want to get some information that ProductController would process this url `https://localhost:8090/name-of-product/147/product`

I have something like this:

```
static class CustomPathContainer implements PathContainer {

        String path;

        CustomPathContainer(String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        static CustomPathContainer of(String path) {
            return new CustomPathContainer(path);
        }

        @Override
        public String value() {
            return path;
        }

        @Override
        public List<Element> elements() {
            return List.of();
        }
    }
```

```
        CustomPathContainer refCustomPathContainer = CustomPathContainer.of("/name-of-product/147/product");
        // Autowired RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping
        Set<Map.Entry<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod>> entries = handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods().entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> handlerMethod : entries) {
            RequestMappingInfo key = handlerMethod.getKey();
            PathPatternsRequestCondition pathPatternsCondition = key.getPathPatternsCondition();
            Set<PathPattern> patterns = pathPatternsCondition.getPatterns();
            for (PathPattern pathPattern : patterns) {
                // Some check if url and pattern match?
                PathPattern.PathMatchInfo matches = pathPattern.matchAndExtract(refCustomPathContainer);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why to not inject HttpServletRequest in your endpoint using Autowired annotation?

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Why do you need the controller? Using a `HandlerInterceptor` and `preHandle` will give you the handler (in this case the `HandlerMethod`). BUt generally when one needs the controller outside of it, it means they are doing things they shouldn't be doing or should be solved differently.

Comment: I need to know from which page (controller) was performed action (something like ajax that is not binded to controllers), and I can only get url referer (String) from current HttpServletRequest telling me which page performed action. And I need to pair result of the action to source of action (in this case to controller)

Comment: You can do it through AOP.

Comment: AOP is not used in this project

Comment: AOP is not illegal :D Anyway just inject an instance of HttpServletRequest in your controller to do that!